# Photoshop layer x/y center registration point coordinates

Tags: javascript, adobe, photoshop

**Goal:**

Design a script that I can run inside of photoshop, that will provide me the x and y coordinates of every layer in the PSD file, and then save that to a text file that I can use to extract said data.

**Progress:**

I have already found a script that will accomplish this, and made my own additions to it.

**Issue:**

My issue is that I am not a very advanced coder, I am trying to get the x and y coordinates of the center registration point of the layer, not top left. I have done hours of research (maybe not asking google the right questions) to try to figure this out. I realize my level of understanding is not on par with actual software developers, and while I respect that, there is no developer that works here and I am kind of left alone to figure this out. I have studied a little javascript, so I understood enough to make small additions to the following code.

**The Code:**

```
// Bring application forward
app.bringToFront();

// Set active Document variable and decode name for output
var docRef = app.activeDocument;
var docName = decodeURI(activeDocument.name);

// Define pixels as unit of measurement
var defaultRulerUnits = preferences.rulerUnits;
preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;

// Define variable for the number of layers in the active document
var layerNum = app.activeDocument.artLayers.length;


// Define variable for the active layer in the active document
var layerRef = app.activeDocument.activeLayer;


// Define varibles for x and y of layers
var x = layerRef.bounds[0].value;
var y = layerRef.bounds[1].value;
var coords = "";

// Loop to iterate through all layers

function recurseLayers(currLayers) {
  for ( var i = 0; i < currLayers.layers.length; i++ ) {
    layerRef = currLayers.layers[i];
    x = layerRef.bounds[0].value;
    y = layerRef.bounds[1].value;
    coords += layerRef.name + ": " + x + "x" + "," + y + "y" + "\n";

//test if it's a layer set

    if ( isLayerSet(currLayers.layers[i]) ) {
      recurseLayers(currLayers.layers[i]);
    }
  }
}

//a test for a layer set

function isLayerSet(layer) {
  try {
    if ( layer.layers.length > 0 ) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  catch(err) {
    return false;
  }
}

// Ask the user for the folder to export to

var FPath = Folder.selectDialog("Save exported coordinates to");

// Detect line feed type

if ( $.os.search(/windows/i) !== -1 ) {
  fileLineFeed = "Windows";
}
else {
  fileLineFeed = "Macintosh";
}

// Export to txt file

function writeFile(info) {
  try {
    var f = new File(FPath + "/" + docName + ".txt");
    f.remove();
    f.open('a');
    f.lineFeed = fileLineFeed;
    f.write(info);
    f.close();
  }
  catch(e){}
}

// Run the functions

recurseLayers(docRef);
preferences.rulerUnits = defaultRulerUnits;

// Set preferences back to user's defaults

writeFile(coords);

// Show results

if ( FPath == null ) {
  alert("Export aborted", "Canceled");
}
else {
  alert("Exported " + layerNum + " layer's coordinates to " + FPath + "/" + 
docName + ".txt " + "using " + fileLineFeed + " line feeds.", "Success!");
}
```

Comment: The Solution I am seeking is to find the center of a layers bounding box (or image bounding box) in the form of x and y coordinates that you would normally have to obtain manually through copy and pasting from photoshops toolbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bounds` property of a layer gives you the top left corner. The middle point is x + half the layer width and y + half the layer height. All you need are the layer dimensions and a little math.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I meant to get back to this. I was able to get it working with that type of information. Thank you